# c string compare vs hash compare

Tags: c, string, hash, compare

I need to compare a string to multiple other constant strings in c. I am curious which is faster, to hash the string I am going to compare and compare it to all the other constant string hashes or just compare the strings as strings. thank you in advance

thank you for the answers I am going to be doing many comparisons. can anyone give me a good, fast, low resource intensive algorithm to use? The only hash I know of is MD5 and I have a feeling that is over kill.

I also want to add that the strings are maybe 20 or 30 characters long at the max with most being around 7.

Answer (score 10):

Is the comparison going to be done once or many times? If the comparison is going to be done only once then you are likely better off doing a straight comparison. If you are going to need to compare very many strings to this set of constant strings, then you can probably save time in the long run by doing it with hashes.

This is a simple enough problem that you can easily write it both ways and see which works better for a representative set of input.

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to get ahead, string hashing functions are O(n).  String comparison is O(n) as well, with a smaller Oh.  You would only be ahead if you can store the hash values you compute and use them repeatedly.  For both.

Simple sample C hash functions [are here](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html).

Comment: What if you were comparing this one string with multiple strings - like the question asks? I don't think its still O(n), it would be O(n^2) right?

Answer (score 4):

Equality of a hash value does not guarantee equality - a mismatch will guarantee inequality, though.  If you're going to need to compare a lot of strings against your collection the a hash would be great - if it's a one-off comparison (unlikely I guess) then strcmp will do nicely.

Comment: Exactly. See also similar "optimization" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186494/ifstr1str2-versus-ifstr1-lengthstr2-length-str1str2/186794#186794

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to match a subject string against a set of other strings, you might consider using the [Aho-Corasick String Matching Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).  It uses a trie to match the subject against all of the target strings in a single pass (it's also quite simple to implement).

Answer (score 3):

I think if you have a static list of strings, I would store them in a sorted array and then use `bsearch` to determine if a string is in that list.  This returns NULL if it does not exist, or a pointer to the value should it exist and is probably faster than a linear search or hashing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* cmp function for qsort and bsearch */
static int pstrcmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  return strcmp(*(char * const *)a, *(char * const *)b);
}

/* check an input against the list of known strings */
static char *check_for_match(char *input)
{
  static char *static_list[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
  static int nelems;

  /* this sorts the list, for demonstration purposes, but if the list
     is static then it could be sorted prior to compiling */
  if (! nelems)
  {
    nelems = sizeof(static_list) / sizeof(*static_list);
    qsort(static_list, nelems, sizeof(*static_list), pstrcmp);
  }


  return bsearch(&input, static_list, nelems, sizeof(*static_list), pstrcmp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (check_for_match("should_not_match"))
  {
    printf("Match found.\n");
  } else {
    printf("No match found.\n");
  }

  if (check_for_match("two"))
  {
    printf("Match found.\n");
  } else {
    printf("No match found.\n");
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  What's the hashing algorithm?  How long are the strings?  What's the platform?

Also note that a matching hash doesn't guarantee matching strings.

Comment: Hashing has no false negatives, but does have false positives.

Answer (score 1):

If your constant strings are known at compile time, take a look at the idea of a "perfect hash".

Wikipedia: A perfect hash function for a set S is a hash function that maps distinct elements in S to distinct integers, with no collisions.

That "no collisions" thing saves you work.  Possibilities for further reading and implementations are:

- cmph -- http://cmph.sourceforge.net/
- gperf -- http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/

Answer (score 0):

It greatly depends on the length of the strings and the complexity of your hash function. Implement and benchmark yourself would be the best answer...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that could work, is to have your constant string sorted and making a dichotomic search of your string, this way you only have at most `log2(n)` comparisons (that's for example only 10 comparisons for 1024 strings or even only 20 for 1000000 strings).
I don't know if it is applicable to your problem but I had really good results with that approach. Hashing is really difficult to get right, the corner cases can get really nasty and the computation of the key can often be quite costly.

Answer (score 0):

> thank you for the answers I am going
>   to be doing many comparisons. can
>   anyone give me a good, fast, low
>   resource intensive algorithm to use?
>   The only hash I know of is MD5 and I
>   have a feeling that is over kill.

[Murmur hash](http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/) is simple, fast and behaves well on statistical tests.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, if you are just comparing if two strings (you can also think about two files, two videos etc), doing a char by char comparison and hashing are both O(N), there is no obvious advantage doing it hash way.

However, if the string can change, then hashing would be more efficient in the 2nd run, e.g., rolling hash https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash

Moreover, hashing of a string/file is like a fingerprint, you can directly compare the hash value next time you want to compare if another string is the same as this one or not