# String Comparison Using Hash

Tags: php, performance, algorithm, hash, compare

So I just came out of an otherwise excellent interview where I happened to have dropped the ball towards the end.  The test I was given involved solving a simple CS question.

You have two stings 

`$a = 'abcd';
$b = 'cdfg';`

Using the most efficient method possible I was asked to compare these two strings and return any matching characters.  At the time, the most obvious (and least efficient) solution was as follows.

`

```
$matches = array();
$length = strlen($a);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if(strpos($b, $a[$i]) !== false) {
        $matches[] = $a[$i];
    }
}

return $matches;
```

I was informed that correct and most efficient solution required the use of hashes.
Could someone please elaborate?

edit:

The return value in this example should be "cd".

I was told that using PHP methods such as "array_intersect" would be considered cheating.

Comment: what do you mean by "any matching characters"? Any common characters? Any characters that match in the exact same position? Something else? Imprecise descriptions waste everybody's time.

Comment: In this example the return value would have been "cd".

Comment: arrays I can understand, but hashes? `var_dump(array_intersect(str_split($a), str_split($b)));`

Comment: That's correct.  We had been running short on time so I figured that I would just ask him what was the most efficient solution to this problem.  It had to something to do with hashing the value of $a.

Comment: arrays I can understand, but hashes? var_dump(array_intersect(str_split($a), str_split($b)));

@Mark Baker

lol, that was actually my first response.  He told me that was cheating though.

Comment: Cool stuff!Even i got to know this now. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435616/c-string-compare-vs-hash-compare

Comment: "I was informed that correct and most efficient solution required the use of hashes" - then you might want to consider yourself lucky not to get the job. This is nonsense. It is only more efficient where the strings are significantly longer than this (more than about 1000 chars)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is `O(strlen($a) * strlen($b))`, as `strpos()` may have to search all of `$b` in order to find a specific character.  By "hashing", I assume they mean "storing the characters of `$a` in a hashtable":

```
$a_hash = array();
$length = strlen($a);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $a_hash[$a[$i]] = true;
}
$matches = array();
$length = strlen($b);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
   if (array_key_exists($a_hash, $b[$i])) {
       $matches[] = $b[$i];
   }
}
return $matches;
```

Assuming that the hashtable operations (using PHP's infamous `array()`) are constant-time, this is now `O(strlen($a) + strlen($b))`.

Comment: I can't believe how freaking obvious this solution was.  Thanks.